# Updating Database using dynamically created form inputs using Play Framework 2

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, playframework, ebean

I have a candidate model and a bunch of other models such as schools, degrees, skills, job positions, etc. that have a one to many relationship with the candidate model.

I was able to make a create form (form that creates a new candidate) that can have form fields dynamically created using javascript/jquery. The user can add more input fields by clicking a "Add Another Button". The form submits to the controller and all the data gets added perfectly fine to the database.

The problem comes into play with the edit form. The edit form is pretty much the same as the create form except it has data pre populated in the form fields from the database. When I submit this form to the update function in the controller it does the update incorrectly. When  I go back to the edit form to see if it worked correctly, there are random input fields with blank values but the data does get edited.

I am fairly new to the play framework and probably am doing something wrong. I did something similar in PHP using Codeigniter and it worked fine. Probably because Codeigniter doesn't use Ebean or JPA.

Below is some of the code that I wrote so my question is more understandable. I'm only going to include the Candidate model and the Schools model because the other ones are similar to the schools model. Also, I included the js code that generates the dynamic form fields.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Candidate.java(model):

    @Entity
    public class Candidate extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    public String firstName;

    public String lastName;

    public boolean sponsorshipStatus;

    public boolean proceedToInterview;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    public String text;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<School> schools;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Degree> degrees;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Document> documents;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<JobPosition> jobPositions;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Skill> skills;

    /**
     * Generic query helper for entity Candidate with id Long
     */
    public static Model.Finder<Long, Candidate> find = new Model.Finder<Long, Candidate>(Long.class, Candidate.class);

    public static Page<Candidate> page(int page, int pageSize, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {
    return find.where()
            .ilike("first_name", "%" + filter + "%")
            .orderBy(sortBy + " " + order)
            .findPagingList(pageSize)
            .setFetchAhead(false).getPage(page);
    }

    }


School.java(model):

    @Entity 
    public class School extends Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    public String schoolName;

    @ManyToOne
    public Candidate candidate;


    /**
     * Generic query helper for entity Company with id Long
     */
    public static Model.Finder<Long, School> find = new Model.Finder<Long, School>(
            Long.class, School.class);

        }

Application.java(controller):



    public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }

    /*display a list of candiates*/

    public static Result list(int page, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {
        return ok(views.html.list.render(Candidate.page(page, 10, sortBy, order, filter), sortBy, order, filter));
    }

    /**
     * Display the 'edit form' of a existing Candidate.
     * 
     * @param id
     *            Id of the candidate to edit
     */
    public static Result edit(Long id) {
        Form<Candidate> candidateForm =    form(Candidate.class).fill(Candidate.find.byId(id));
        Candidate candidate = Candidate.find.byId(id);
        return ok(views.html.editForm.render(id, candidateForm, candidate));
    }

    /**
     * Handle the 'edit form' submission
     * 
     * @param id
     *            Id of the computer to edit
     */
    public static Result update(Long id) {
        RequestBody request_body = request().body();
        MultipartFormData body = request_body.asMultipartFormData();

        // MultipartFormData FilePart object list
        List<FilePart> files = body.getFiles();
        List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<Document>();

        for (FilePart file : files) {
            String fileName = file.getFilename();
            // Use Java.IO File class to move file in desired location
            File f = file.getFile();

            File nf = new File("\\\\WL-MSAMARITONI\\Images", fileName);
            f.renameTo(nf);

            Document doc;
            doc = new Document();

            doc.docName = fileName;
            doc.filePath = nf.getAbsolutePath();
            docs.add(doc);

        }
        Form<Candidate> candidateForm = form(Candidate.class).bindFromRequest();
        Candidate updateCandidate = candidateForm.get();
        updateCandidate.documents = docs;
        /*while(updateCandidate.degrees.remove(null));
        while(updateCandidate.jobPositions.remove(null));
        while(updateCandidate.schools.remove(null));
        while(updateCandidate.skills.remove(null));
        while(updateCandidate.documents.remove(null));
    */

        updateCandidate.update(id);
        updateCandidate.save();
        flash("success", "Candidate " + candidateForm.get().firstName + " has been     created");
        return redirect("/candidate/" + id);

    }

    /**
     * Display the 'new candidate form'.
     */
    public static Result create() {
        Form<Candidate> candidateForm = form(Candidate.class);
        return ok(views.html.createForm.render(candidateForm));
    }

    /**
     * Handle the 'new candidate form' submission
     */
    public static Result save() {

        RequestBody request_body = request().body();
        MultipartFormData body = request_body.asMultipartFormData();

        // MultipartFormData FilePart object list
        List<FilePart> files = body.getFiles();
        List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<Document>();

        for (FilePart file : files) {
            String fileName = file.getFilename();
            // Use Java.IO File class to move file in desired location
            File f = file.getFile();

            File nf = new File("\\\\WL-MSAMARITONI\\Images", fileName);
            f.renameTo(nf);

            Document doc;
            doc = new Document();

            doc.docName = fileName;
            doc.filePath = nf.getAbsolutePath();
            docs.add(doc);

        }
        Form<Candidate> candidateForm = form(Candidate.class).bindFromRequest();
        Candidate newCandidate = candidateForm.get();
        newCandidate.documents = docs;
        newCandidate.save();

        flash("success", "Computer " + candidateForm.get().firstName + " has been   created");
        return redirect("/candidates/new");
    }

    }




createForm.scala.html(view):

    @(candidateForm: Form[Candidate])

    @import helper._


    @main("Create Candidate"){

    <h1>Add a New Candidate</h1>

     @form(routes.Application.save(), args= 'class -> "form-horizontal",'enctype ->       "multipart/form-data") {
     <div class="row">
     <fieldset class="span6">
        <legend>
            <h3> Add Candidate Info</h3>
        </legend>
        @inputText(candidateForm("firstName"), '_label -> "First Name")
        @inputText(candidateForm("lastName"), '_label -> "Last Name")
        @checkbox(candidateForm("sponsorshipStatus"), '_label -> "Sponsorship   Status")
        @checkbox(candidateForm("proceedToInterview"), '_label -> "Proceed to  Interview")
        @textarea(candidateForm("text"), args = 'rows -> 3, 'cols -> 50, '_label -> "Notes")
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="span6">
        <legend>
            <h3>Add Schools</h3>
        </legend>
        <div id="schools" class="control-group">
            <div class="school hidden_form_default">
                <input id="chk_school" type="checkbox">
                <input disabled="disabled" id="school" name="schools[].schoolName" placeholder="Enter School">
            </div>
            <div class="school">
                <input id="chk_school_0" type="checkbox" value="1">
                <input id="school_0" name="schools[0].schoolName"   placeholder="Enter School" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn school_add_button">
            Add Another
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger school_delete_button">
            Delete Checked
        </button>
    </fieldset>
</div>
    <div class="row">
        <fieldset class="span6">
            <legend>                              

    <h3>Add Degrees</h3>
             </legend>
        <div id="degrees" class="control-group">
            <div class="degree hidden_form_default">
                <input id="chk_degree"  class="" type="checkbox" value="1">
                <input id="degreeLevel" disabled="disabled" class="" name="degrees[].degreeLevel" placeholder="Degree Level" >
                <input id="degreeFocus" disabled="disabled" class="" name="degrees[].degreeFocus" placeholder="Degree Focus" >
                <input type="text" id="completedDate" disabled="disabled" class="datepicker input-small" name="degrees[].completedDate" placeholder="Completed" >
            </div>
            <div class= "degree">
                <input id="chk_degree_0" class="" type="checkbox" value="1">
                <input id="degreeLevel_0" class="" name="degrees[0].degreeLevel" placeholder="Degree Level" >
                <input id="degreeFocus_0" class="" name="degrees[0].degreeFocus" placeholder="Degree Focus" >
                <input type="text" id="completedDate_0" class="datepicker input-small" name="degrees[0].completedDate" placeholder="Completed" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn degree_add_button">
            Add Another
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger degree_delete_button">
            Delete Checked
        </button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="span6">
        <legend>
            <h3>Add Skills</h3>
        </legend>
        <div id="skills" class="control-group">
            <div class="skill hidden_form_default">
                <input id="chk_skill" type="checkbox">
                <input disabled="disabled" id="skill" name="skills[].skill" class="clearMeFocus" placeholder="Enter skill">
            </div>
            <div class="skill">
                <input id="chk_skill_0" type="checkbox" value="1">
                <input id="skill_0" name="skills[0].skill" class="clearMeFocus" placeholder="Enter skill" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn skill_add_button">
            Add Another
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger skill_delete_button">
            Delete Checked
        </button>
    </fieldset>
</div>
    <div class="row">
        <fieldset class="span6">
            <legend>

    <h3>Add Desired Positions</h3>
            </legend>
        <div id="positions" class="control-group">
            <div class="position hidden_form_default">
                <input id="chk_position"  class="" type="checkbox" value="1">
                <input id="position" disabled="disabled" class="" name="jobPositions[].position" placeholder="Enter Position" >
            </div>
            <input id="chk_position_0" class="" type="checkbox" value="1">
            <input id="positionLevel_0" class="" name="jobPositions[0].position" placeholder="Enter Position" >

        </div>
        <button class="btn position_add_button">
            Add Another
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger position_delete_button">
            Delete Checked
        </button>
    </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="span6">
        <legend>
            <h3>Add Documents</h3>
        </legend>
        <div id="documents" class="control-group">
            <div class="document hidden_form_default">
                <input id="chk_document" type="checkbox">
                <input type="file" disabled="disabled" id="document" name="documents[]">
            </div>
            <div class="document">
                <input id="chk_document_0" type="checkbox" value="1">
                <input id="document_0" type="file" name="documents[0]" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn document_add_button">
            Add Another
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger document_delete_button">
            Delete Checked
        </button>
    </fieldset>

    </div>
    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary control">
    Add Candidate
    </button>

    }
    }


editForm.scala.html(view)

    @(id: Long, candidateForm: Form[Candidate], candidate: Candidate)

    @import helper._

    @main("Edit Candidate") {

    <h1>Edit Candidate</h1>

    @form(routes.Application.update(id), args= 'class -> "form-horizontal",'enctype ->     "multipart/form-data", 'id -> "updateForm") {

    <div class="row">
    <fieldset class="span6">
        <legend>

    <h3> Edit Candidate Info</h3>
        </legend>
        @inputText(candidateForm("firstName"), '_label -> "First Name")
        @inputText(candidateForm("lastName"), '_label -> "Last Name")
        @checkbox(candidateForm("sponsorshipStatus"), '_label -> "Sponsorship Status")
        @checkbox(candidateForm("proceedToInterview"), '_label -> "Proceed to Interview")
        @textarea(candidateForm("text"), args = 'rows -> 3, 'cols -> 50, '_label -> "Notes")
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="span6">
        <legend>
            <h3>Add Schools</h3>
        </legend>


        <div id="schools" class="control-group">
            <div class="school hidden_form_default">
                <input id="chk_school" type="checkbox">
                <input disabled="disabled" id="school" name="schools[].schoolName" placeholder="Enter School">
            </div>
            @for(school <- candidate.schools) {
            <div class="school">
                <input id="chk_school_@school.id" type="checkbox" value="@school.id">
                <input id="school_@school.id" name="schools[@school.id].schoolName" value="@school.schoolName" placeholder="Enter School" >
                <input type="hidden" id="schoolId_@school.id" class="" name="schools[@school.id].id" value="@school.id">
            </div>


            } 
            <div class="school new_field_div">
                <input id="chk_school_0" type="checkbox" value="1">
                <input id="school_0" name="schools[0].schoolName" placeholder="Enter School" >
            </div>

        </div>
        <button class="btn school_add_button">
            Add Another
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger school_delete_button">
            Delete Checked
        </button>
    </fieldset>
</div>
    <div class="row">
        <fieldset class="span6">
        <legend>

    <h3>Add Degrees</h3>
        </legend>
        <div id="degrees" class="control-group">
            <div class="degree hidden_form_default">
                <input id="chk_degree"  class="" type="checkbox" value="1">
                <input id="degreeLevel" disabled="disabled" class="" name="degrees[].degreeLevel" placeholder="Degree Level" >
                <input id="degreeFocus" disabled="disabled" class="" name="degrees[].degreeFocus" placeholder="Degree Focus" >
                <input type="text" id="completedDate" disabled="disabled" class="datepicker input-small" name="degrees[].completedDate" placeholder="Completed" >
            </div>
            @for(degree <- candidate.degrees) {
                <div class ="degree">
                    <input id="chk_degree_@degree.id" class="" type="checkbox" value="@degree.id">
                    <input id="degreeLevel_@degree.id" class="" name="degrees[@degree.id].degreeLevel" value="@degree.degreeLevel" placeholder="Degree Level" >
                    <input id="degreeFocus_@degree.id" class="" name="degrees[@degree.id].degreeFocus" value="@degree.degreeFocus" placeholder="Degree Focus" >
                    <input type="hidden" id="degreeId_@degree.id" class="" name="degrees[@degree.id].id" value="@degree.id">

                    <input type="text" id="completedDate_@degree.id" class="datepicker input-small" name="degrees[@degree.id].completedDate" value="@degree.completedDate" placeholder="Completed" >
                </div>
            }

            <div class ="degree new_field_div">
                <input id="chk_degree_0" class="" type="checkbox" value="1">
                <input id="degreeLevel_0" class="" name="degrees[0].degreeLevel" placeholder="Degree Level" >
                <input id="degreeFocus_0" class="" name="degrees[0].degreeFocus" placeholder="Degree Focus" >
                <input type="text" id="completedDate_0" class="datepicker input-small" name="degrees[0].completedDate" placeholder="Completed" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn degree_add_button">
            Add Another
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger degree_delete_button">
            Delete Checked
        </button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="span6">
        <legend>
            <h3>Add Skills</h3>
        </legend>
        <div id="skills" class="control-group">
            <div class="skill hidden_form_default">
                <input id="chk_skill" type="checkbox">
                <input disabled="disabled" id="skill" name="skills[].skill" class="clearMeFocus" placeholder="Enter skill">
            </div>
            @for(skill <- candidate.skills) {
                <div class="skill">
                    <input id="chk_skill_@skill.id" type="checkbox" value="@skill.id">
                    <input id="skill_@skill.id" name="skills[@skill.id].skill" class="clearMeFocus" value="@skill.skill" placeholder="Enter skill" >
                    <input type="hidden" id="skillId_@skill.id" class="" name="skills[@skill.id].id" value="@skill.id">
                </div>
            }
            <div class="skill new_field_div">
                <input id="chk_skill_0" type="checkbox" value="1">
                <input id="skill_0" name="skills[0].skill" class="clearMeFocus" placeholder="Enter skill" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn skill_add_button">
            Add Another
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger skill_delete_button">
            Delete Checked
        </button>
    </fieldset>
</div>
    <div class="row">
    <fieldset class="span6">
        <legend>

    <h3>Add Desired Positions</h3>
        </legend>
        <div id="positions" class="control-group">
            <div class="position hidden_form_default">
                <input id="chk_position"  class="" type="checkbox" value="1">
                <input id="position" disabled="disabled" class="" name="jobPositions[].position" placeholder="Enter Position" >
            </div>
            @for(position <- candidate.jobPositions) {
                <div class="position">
                    <input id="chk_position_@position.id" class="" type="checkbox" value="@position.id">
                    <input id="positionLevel_@position.id" class="" name="jobPositions[@position.id].position" value="@position.position" placeholder="Enter Position" >
                    <input type="hidden" id="positionId_@position.id" class="" name="jobPositions[@position.id].id" value="@position.id">
                </div>
            }
            <div class="position new_field_div">
                <input id="chk_position_0" class="" type="checkbox" value="1">
                <input id="positionLevel_0" class="" name="jobPositions[0].position" placeholder="Enter Position" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn position_add_button">
            Add Another
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger position_delete_button">
            Delete Checked
        </button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="span6">
        <legend>
            <h3>Add Documents</h3>
        </legend>
        <div id="documents" class="control-group">
            <div class="document hidden_form_default">
                <input id="chk_document" type="checkbox">
                <input type="file" disabled="disabled" id="document" name="documents[]">
            </div>
            @for(document <- candidate.documents) {
                <div class="document">
                    <input id="chk_document_@document.id" type="checkbox" value="@document.id">
                    <input type="hidden" id="documentId_@document.id" class="" name="documents[@document.id].id" value="@document.id">
                    <p>@document.docName</p>
                </div>
            }

            <div class="document new_field_div">
                <input id="chk_document_0" type="checkbox" value="1">
                <input id="document_0" type="file" name="documents[0]" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn document_add_button">
            Add Another
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger document_delete_button">
            Delete Checked
        </button>
    </fieldset>

</div>

    <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" value="Save this Candidate" class="btn primary">
    or <a href="@routes.Application.list()" class="btn">Cancel</a>
    </div>
    }


    }


main.js:

    $(function () {
    var delete_form_url = "/school/delete"
    add_another_form_field('.school_add_button', '.school', '#schools', 'schoolName', '.school_delete_button', delete_form_url);
    add_another_form_field('.degree_add_button', '.degree', '#degrees', 'degreeName', '.degree_delete_button', delete_form_url);
    add_another_form_field('.skill_add_button', '.skill', '#skills', 'skillName', '.skill_delete_button', delete_form_url);
    add_another_form_field('.position_add_button', '.position', '#positions', 'positionName', '.position_delete_button', delete_form_url);
    add_another_form_field('.document_add_button', '.document', '#documents', 'documentName', '.document_delete_button', delete_form_url);
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();

    $("#updateForm").submit(function (event) {

        $(".new_field_div").each(function () {
            var isNull = false;
            var new_field_inputs = $(this).find("input:text");

            new_field_inputs.each(function (index, element) {
                console.log($(element).val());
                if ($(element).val()) {
                    isNull = false;
                    return false;
                } else {
                    isNull = true;
                }

            });
            if (isNull) {
                $(this).remove();
            }

        });

    });

    });

    function add_another_form_field(add_button_class, child_div_class, parent_element_id,    field_name, delete_button_class, delete_form_url) {
    var num = 1;
    $(add_button_class).on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var cloned_fields = $(child_div_class + ":first").clone();
        console.log(cloned_fields);
        cloned_fields.find('input,textarea,select').attr('id', function (i, val) {
            if (val !== undefined) {
                return val + '_' + num;
            }
        });

        cloned_fields.find('label').attr('for', function (i, val) {
            if (val !== undefined) {
                return val + '_' + num;
            }
        });
        cloned_fields.find('input,textarea,select').attr('name', function (i, val) {
            if (val !== undefined) {
                return val.replace(/\[\]/, "[" + num + "]");
            }
        });

        cloned_fields.removeClass("hidden_form_default");
        cloned_fields.addClass("new_field_div");

        cloned_fields.find('input').prop('disabled', false);

        cloned_fields.appendTo(parent_element_id);
        num++;

        // clear the new inputs on click
        // clear input on focus
        $(".clearMeFocus").focus(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr("title")) {
                clearMePrevious = $(this).val();
                $(this).val("");
            }
        });

        // if field is empty afterward, add text again
        $(".clearMeFocus").blur(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).val(clearMePrevious);
            }
        });

    });

    $(delete_button_class).click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).parents('form');
        var table_name = form.find('input[name="table_name"]').val();
        $(child_div_class).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked:enabled').each(function  (index, child) {
            table_row_id = $(child).val();
            if (table_row_id) {
                $.post(delete_form_url, {
                    table_name: table_name,
                    table_row_id: table_row_id
                });
            }
            // delete from view

            $(child).parents().remove(child_div_class);
        });

    });

    }
```

Comment: Consider creating a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Your code sample is huge, and it's less likely to get help when expecting people to dig through 650 lines (yes, I counted them)! Also, your question is hard to find - it's hidden in another wall of text, above your code :) Of course, attempts to explain precisely everything are very good, but I think it would help if you would possibly make this more concise.

Comment: Yah I figured that would be an issue. I just couldn't find the best way to explain my issue without including everything. I'll write it over and I'll try and make it shorter. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: " fields with blank values" Which fields do not get updated? I would like to know which fields are not updated instead of a whole story about PHP / JPA etc..

Comment: Thanks for responding! The fields with the proper ids get updated but there are a bunch of blank fields with auto-generated ids being added and I can't seem to figure out why that these blank fields are being added when I submit the form. I believe it's because of how JPA/Ebean works but not sure.